# Partitions in Informatica / Oracle tables

Tags: etl

In my project they talk about Informatica job to drop and the re-create 'weekly/monthly partitions' every time it runs. Does that mean that the  weekly/monthly partitions need to be created in Informatica or Oracle tables?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it means you need to have partitioned table , you can have range partition, in your case it can be daily/weekly/monthly partition. when you create new one , if older data is not required you can delete partition.

[Informatica reference](https://marketplace.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/Readme_2653.pdf)

[Oracle reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm)